# PHPexcel how to display cell values into a webpage including image

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am able to display values from a excel file(.xls) using below code i managed to get the values by executing the `print_r`, now my next step is to display each rows inside a HTML table, this file also contains image located on the last column but i cannot see any text that i can convert into image, any suggestions would be great!Thanks in advance!

```
<?php

//  Include PHPExcel_IOFactory
/** Include PHPExcel_IOFactory */
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

$inputFileName = 'userimage.xls';

//  Read your Excel workbook
try {
    $inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFileName);
    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
} catch(Exception $e) {
    die('Error loading file "'.pathinfo($inputFileName,PATHINFO_BASENAME).'": '.$e->getMessage());
}

//  Get worksheet dimensions
$sheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0); 
$highestRow = $sheet->getHighestRow(); 
$highestColumn = $sheet->getHighestColumn();

//  Loop through each row of the worksheet in turn
for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; $row++){ 
    //  Read a row of data into an array
    $rowData = $sheet->rangeToArray('A' . $row . ':' . $highestColumn . $row,
                                    NULL,
                                    TRUE,
                                    FALSE);


        print_r($rowData);


}
```

My output

[image]

Comment: Perhaps using PHPExcel's built-in HTML Writer?

Comment: Or if you want to use your own code to display everything, at least take a look at how the HTML Writer does it

Comment: Thanks i will look into it.